# How to parse a String to int and not get the next errors?

Tags: flutter, casting, integer, unhandled

With`var pinU = int.parse(pin.text);` I get this error:

```
E/flutter (16045): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)
E/flutter (16045):
E/flutter (16045): ^
```

With `var pinU = pin as int;` I get this error:

```
E/flutter (16045): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
```

I'm trying to pass a PIN to the database helper function to get the results.
Here is my complete function:

```
login2() async {
    var usernameU = username.text;
    var pinU = int.parse(pin.text);

    await DBProvider.db.getUser(usernameU, pinU).then((tempUser) {
      Navigator.push(context as BuildContext,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const WelcomePage()));
    }).catchError((err) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Error: $err');
    });
  }
```

I need to pass a int, but this error is persistent.

Comment: What is 'pin'? Show how it is declared.

Comment: 1. Don't try to parse empty strings. 2. If you're parsing untrusted input from a user, use [`int.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/int/tryParse.html) instead.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin it is declared here: final TextEditingController pin = TextEditingController();

Comment: @jamesdlin how to add checks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of var use int as datatype.

```
int pinU = int.parse(pin.text ?? "0");
```

Comment: with your solution I'm getting this error: 'The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed.
Try removing the operator and the right operand.'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (pin.text.isEmpty) {
   // tell a user that this field is required or do something else
   return;
}

final pinU = int.parse(pin.text);
```

You also need to set your TextField to accept only numbers, or you should use tryParse instead.